# I get empty form data in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, ionic3

When i append my parameters in formData, then i console formData. I received empty formData. I want to set all parameters in formData. 
How can i set formData in ionic 3?

I have using

```
 let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;  

 let file = fileList[0];   

 let formData:FormData = new FormData();  

 formData.append('User_Id', this.userId);
 console.log("formData: User_Id", formData);

  formData.append('sessionId', this.sessionId);
  console.log("formData: sessionId", formData);

  formData.append('File_Name',file, file.name);  
 console.log("formData: File_Name", formData);


  formData.append('File_Description', "new file created");
  console.log("formData: File_Description", formData);

  formData.append('Categories_Id', "1");
  console.log("formData: Categories_Id", formData);

  console.log("formData:", formData);
```

Comment: Please read this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8125#issuecomment-265514682

Comment: yes, I did use this solution, but there is also getting error of ** ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property '_backend' on string 'post'** on post.call method

Comment: Please update your question with latest code changes and error

Answer (score 0):

As per the FormData documentation(link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), you can append formdata by using below methods:
two parameter version:

```
formData.append('key', 'value');
```

three parameter version:

```
formData.append('key', 'value', 'filename');
```

// Code to display the keys:

```
for (var key of formData.keys()) {
   console.log(key); 
}
```

// Code to display the values:

```
for (var value of formData.values()) {
   console.log(value); 
}
```

So please use above code to retrieve formdata instead using `console.log("formData:", formData);`

Also while sending formadata you can use below code:

```
var payload = { content: formData };
HTTP.call( 'POST','your own server url', payload);
```

If above is not working then please refer below code:

```
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
```

Then use below code:

```
let payload = JSON.stringify( formData );
var headerObj: any = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
let headers = new Headers( headerObj );
let options = new RequestOptions( { headers: headers });

this.http.post( url, payload, options );
```

Comment: I did use this solution, but there is also getting error of ** ERROR TypeError: Cannot create property '_backend' on string 'post'** on post.call method

Comment: @Binita Doriwala, I have updated the answer, please check the same.